# How can I create and use 404.vue in Inertiajs2 app?

Tags: inertiajs

How with laravel, Inertiajs2, vuejs3  can I catch invalid url ?
If I create file

```
resources/views/errors/404.blade.php
```

is it triggered, but I dislike using blade file in this case...

**Additive information :**

I modified file app/Exceptions/Handler.php

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{

```
...
public function render($request, Throwable $e)
{
    $response = parent::render($request, $e);

    // I commented environment checking for development
    if ( /*!app()->environment(['local', 'testing']) &&*/ in_array($response->status(), [500, 503, 404, 403])) {

        // As I want to show separate file for any error I try 404
        return Inertia::render('404', ['status' => $response->status()])
                      ->toResponse($request)
                      ->setStatusCode($response->status());
    } else if ($response->status() === 419) {
        return back()->with([
            'message' => 'The page expired, please try again.',
        ]);
    }

    return $response;
}
```

I created a file resources/js/Pages/404.vue with lines :

```
<template>

    <frontend-layout>

        resources/js/Pages/404.vue

    </frontend-layout>


</template>

<script>
import FrontendLayout from '@/Layouts/FrontendLayout'

import {ref, computed, onMounted} from 'vue'
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
    name: '404Page',
    components: {
        FrontendLayout,
    },
    setup() {
        function HomeOnMounted() {
        } // function HomeOnMounted() {

        onMounted(HomeOnMounted)

        return { // setup return
            // Page state
        }
    }, // setup() {

})
</script>
```

and I got error :

```
[2022-05-18 09:52:14] local.ERROR: Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: View [app] not found. in /ProjectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/FileViewFinder.php:137
Stack trace:
    #0 /ProjectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/FileViewFinder.php(79): Illuminate\View\FileViewFinder->findInPaths()
#1 /ProjectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Factory.php(137): Illuminate\View\FileViewFinder->find()
#2 /ProjectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ResponseFactory.php(87): Illuminate\View\Factory->make()
#3 /ProjectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php(337): Illuminate\Routing\ResponseFactory->view()
#4 /ProjectPath/vendor/inertiajs/inertia-laravel/src/Response.php(113): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic()
#5 /ProjectPath/app/Exceptions/Handler.php(52): Inertia\Response->toResponse()
#6 /ProjectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php(220): App\Exceptions\Handler->render()
#7 /ProjectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php(197): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->renderHttpResponse()
#8 /ProjectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php(255): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleException()
#9 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\{closure}()
#10 {main}
thrown {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\ErrorHandler\\Error\\FatalError(code: 0): Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: View [app] not found. in /ProjectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/FileViewFinder.php:137
    Stack trace:
        #0 /ProjectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/FileViewFinder.php(79): Illuminate\\View\\FileViewFinder->findInPaths()
    #1 /ProjectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Factory.php(137): Illuminate\\View\\FileViewFinder->find()
    #2 /ProjectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ResponseFactory.php(87): Illuminate\\View\\Factory->make()
    #3 /ProjectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php(337): Illuminate\\Routing\\ResponseFactory->view()
    #4 /ProjectPath/vendor/inertiajs/inertia-laravel/src/Response.php(113): Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Facade::__callStatic()
    #5 /ProjectPath/app/Exceptions/Handler.php(52): Inertia\\Response->toResponse()
    #6 /ProjectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php(220): App\\Exceptions\\Handler->render()
    #7 /ProjectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php(197): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->renderHttpResponse()
    #8 /ProjectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php(255): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->handleException()
    #9 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\{closure}()
    #10 {main}
    thrown at /ProjectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/FileViewFinder.php:137)
[stacktrace]
#0 /ProjectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php(244): Symfony\\Component\\ErrorHandler\\Error\\FatalError->__construct(message: '...', code: '...', error: '...', traceOffset: '...', traceArgs: '...', trace: '...')
#1 /ProjectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php(231): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->fatalErrorFromPhpError(error: '...', traceOffset: '...')
#2 /ProjectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php(255): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->handleShutdown()
#3 /ProjectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php(0): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\{closure:/ProjectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php:254-256}()
#4 {main}
"} 


as I have 3 layouts (without default app) I have 3 files :
resources/views/layouts/adminlte.blade.php
resources/views/layouts/frontend.blade.php
resources/views/layouts/user.blade.php
```

and in app/Http/Middleware/HandleInertiaRequests.php I have :

```
public function rootView(Request $request)
{

    if ($request->segment(1) == 'user') {
        return 'layouts/user';
    }
    if ($request->segment(1) == 'admin') {
        return 'layouts/adminlte'; 
    }

    return 'layouts/frontend'; 
}
```

I added one more file : /resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php

But I still got error :

```
 View [app] not found
```

Looks like all defaults error codes demands standard /resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php file,
but why I still got error after I added this file ?

**Additive information # 2:**
Checking provided link I see that file under vendor is used
Project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/views/404.blade.php

If there is a way to copy this file under Project/resources/views/vendor/ and which must be path of this file ?

File resources/js/Pages/error.vue is not opened, even with code in

```
app/Exceptions/Handler.php :
    return Inertia::render('error', ['status' => $response->status()])
        ->toResponse($request)
        ->setStatusCode($response->status());
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you ever fix this? im running against the same problem..

Comment: 5 minutes later...

I fixed it with Inertia::setRootView('layouts/user'); before the return Inertia::render

Answer (score 3):

Error handling is described in the [Inertia.js docs](https://inertiajs.com/error-handling).

You need to extend the render() method in your App\Exceptions\Handler.php so it will send a Inertia response back to the client when it hits an error.

It's important to return an Inertia response only in certain scenarios, because doing this will prevent the default Laravel error handling from running and you won't get the useful debug info during development. The code bellow only returns an Inertia response in production.

```php
use Throwable;
use Inertia\Inertia;

/**
 * Prepare exception for rendering.
 *
 * @param  \Throwable  $e
 * @return \Throwable
 */
public function render($request, Throwable $e)
{
    $response = parent::render($request, $e);

    if (!app()->environment(['local', 'testing']) {
        return Inertia::render('Error', ['status' => $response->status()])
            ->toResponse($request)
            ->setStatusCode($response->status());
    }

    return $response;
}
```

Comment: Please read  Additive information

Comment: You're changing the `rootView` base path. You probably need to have an `app.bldade.php` inside each path.

Comment: Please read Additive information # 2

Answer (score 2):

In **Laravel 10** code *App\Exceptions\Handler* can be implemented like this:

```
// ....
public function register(): void
{
    $this->reportable(function (\Throwable $e) {
        //
    });

    // $this->renderable(function (\Exception $e, $request) {
        // handle for all errors
    // });

    $this->renderable(function (\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException $e, Request $request) {
        return Inertia::render('Error', ['status' => $e->getStatusCode(), 'message' => $e->getMessage()])
            ->toResponse($request)
            ->setStatusCode($e->getStatusCode());
    });
}
// ...
```

Documentation Inertia: [error-handling](https://legacy.inertiajs.com/error-handling).

Documentation Laravel: [rendering-exceptions](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/errors#rendering-exceptions).